# how do i connect local hive to snowflake?

Tags: hive, snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have gone through the steps in snowflake documentation to configure a connector between hive and snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-hive.html#step-1-install-the-connector

But i cant see the hive tables or even a connection command in snowflake history.

snow-config.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.username</name>
    <value>user</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.password</name>
    <value>pwd</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.role</name>
    <value>ACCOUNTADMIN</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.account</name>
    <value>ac name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.db</name>
    <value>db</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.schema</name>
    <value>schema</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>snowflake.jdbc.connection</name>
    <value>account</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I placed the connection jar in hive jar aux path.
[image]

Added this in hive-site.xml

```
 <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.event.listeners</name>
  <value>net.snowflake.hivemetastoreconnector.SnowflakeHiveListener</value>
 </property>
```

restarted hive metastore

```
hive --service metastore
```

**It's stuck here :**
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: That message sounds like either 1) You got the wrong mysql driver 2) your metastore is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

There are changes in connector API:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The old class name has been deprecated.

In your hive-site.xml update this property:

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
```

Change:

```
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
```

to:

```
<value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</value>
```